# Packages only working "once" after install

Tags: package, use-package

I'm trying to get `git-gutter-fringe+` working under emacs 24.5.5 on OS X, but I'm having some trouble. In general, it works fine upon install, but on subsequent restarts the package is not loaded.

I'm using `req-package` to manage package installation and init, and my config for `git-gutter-fringe+` is (currently) as follows:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'el-get)
  (package-install 'el-get))
(unless (package-installed-p 'req-package)
  (package-install 'req-package))
(package-initialize)
(require 'req-package)

;; ...other packages and config...

(req-package git-gutter-fringe+
             :requires (fringe-helper)
             :init
             (progn
               (global-git-gutter-mode)
               (git-gutter-fr+-minimal)
               (setq-default left-fringe-width  16)
               (setq-default right-fringe-width 16)
               ))
```

I've tried variations on this, including simply:

```
(req-package git-gutter-fringe+
             :init (git-gutter-fr+-minimal))
```

...but after the initial install and load, it fails to work.

I've had a look at the package's files under `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` and I can see that the `git-gutter-fringe+-autoloads.el` file looks mostly commented out:

```
;;; git-gutter-fringe+-autoloads.el --- automatically extracted autoloads
;;
;;; Code:
(add-to-list 'load-path (or (file-name-directory #$) (car load-path)))


;;;### (autoloads nil nil ("git-gutter-fringe+.el") (22118 3236 355828
;;;;;;  0))
```

Is this to be expected? How can I diagnose the issue?

As an aside, I've had the same issue previously with the `alchemist` package, though since uninstalling/reinstalling a few times, it's since been pretty stable.

Comment: Do you have the standard `(require 'package)` and `(package-initialize)` near the top of your `.emacs` file?

Comment: @lawlist yes; question updated with relevant config

Comment: `(package-initialise)` is spelled incorrectly -- perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: @lawlist heh, typo when copying the example across from my config :)